# Custom configuration file in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, import

I'm building an ASP.Net MVC4 application and the customer wants to be able to supply an XML configuration file, to configure a vendor list in the application, something like this:

```
<Vendor>
    <Vendor name="ABC Computers" deliveryDays="10"/>
    <Vendor name="XYZ Computers" deliveryDays="15"/>
</Vendors>
```

The file needs to be dropped onto a network location (i.e. not on the web server) and I don't have a database to import  and store the data.

The customer also wants the ability to update it daily. So I'm thinking I'll have to do some kind of import (and validate the file) when the application starts up.

Any good ideas on the best way to accomplish this?
- The data needs to be quickly accessible
- Ideally I just want to import/store it once, or be able to access it quickly
- I need to be able to validate the file, so it might be prudent to be able to be able to switch to a backup

One thought was to use something like Entity Framework and simply read the file whenever I needed it, but if possible I'd hold it in memory in the application if possible.

Cheers
Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to import it into a database or use Entity Framework. You can simply use .NET Xml Serialization to accomplish this.

The command line tool [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.71%29.aspx) will generate c# classes from your Xml file. From the command line:

```
xsd.exe myfile.xml
xsd.exe /c myfile.xsd
```

The first command will infer and create an xml schema file (myfile.xsd) from your xml. The second command will convert the schema file to c# classes.

Then use the [XmlSerializer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to deserialize your xml file into objects (assuming multiple objects in one file):

```
MyCollection myObjects= null;
string path = "mydata.xml";

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyCollection));

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
myObjects = (MyCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

You can use the .xsd file generated above to validate your xml files. Here's a link showing how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162371.aspx.